# Flutter FirebaseAnimatedList rebuilds and moves widgets that have specific index to another place

Tags: firebase, flutter, chat

I have a chat which queries messages from `firebase`.

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: ChatService.instance.getMessagesQuery(widget.recipientUid),
        reverse: false,
        controller: scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int x) {
          return buildRow(x, snapshot);
        })
```

I am trying to build a `Text widget` every time a message comes from new `sent on day` compared to previous as so

```
Widget buildRow(int index, snapshot) {
    List<Widget> rows = [];
    ChatMessage chatMessage = fromMap(snapshot);
    if (chatMessage.messageTimeStamp.day != lastMessage?.messageTimeStamp.day) {
      rows.add(Text(chatMessage.messageTimeStamp.toShortString()));
      lastMessage = chatMessage;
    }
    rows.add(buildChatRow(index, chatMessage));
    return Column(
      children: [...rows],
    );
}
```

When I open my chat, it seems ok

[image]

But as soon as I scroll down and scroll up a bit, it gets rebuilt and places time on different place.
[image]

Ideas please

Comment: In your `buildRow()` function you access `lastMessage`, where and how is it initialized?

Comment: @EimantasG In Stateful Widget
```class _ChatViewState extends State<ChatView> {
  ChatMessage? lastMessage;```

Comment: Are you adding unique keys to those widgets?

Comment: @RomanJaquez I do not